# Redirect certain pages from http to https; redirect rest of site to www

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

My requirements are as follows:

- Certain pages of my site need to use https
- The rest can use http
- I also need to redirect everything to use a www. prefix (e.g., if someone visits domain.com it redirects to www.domain.com)

I've tried a number of solutions listed here on Stack Overflow, but none seems to work.

Here's the relevant portion of my htaccess file:

```
#force https for certain pages    
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(login2\-test\.php.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]

#redirect all pages to www
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Redirecting all pages to www works fine. However, the redirect of login2-test?Switch=ftr (which is in the reg/ subdirectory) to https results in no match, so the page is displayed using http.

I've rewritten that line as follows:

```
RewriteRule ^(reg\/)(login2\-test\.php.*)$ https:www.domain.com/$1$2 [L,R]
```

This at least matched / redirected to https, however the browser could not resolve it.

I've swapped the order of the rules (e.g., www redirect first); that didn't help.

I would appreciate any help -- I've been struggling with this for a while now.

Comment: what is the page names you want to redirect to https? I don't think your regex or page matching is correct.

Comment: I agree with you, I just can't see where I'm getting it wrong. The page name is domain.com/reg/login-test2.php?Switch=ftr

I should mention that I did a test redirecting domain.com/about.php to https and it worked -- note that about.php is at the top level, not in the reg directory.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```